# Chrome extension: get inner text of clicked element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm making an extension that saves the `innerText` of an HTML element (that may be `<a>`) on a click.

I want the extension to become active on a keystroke, like `l` and that would deactivate any `<a>` elements and allow me to click on the element and collect it's `innerText` in my extension logic.

How could I activate the extension with an `l` keystroke?
And when its active, must I add an `onclick` event to each element on the page which sends the clicked element `innerText` and temporarily disable each `<a>`?

Is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: You'll need a *content script* with a standard DOM listener on `document` for `keypress` and `click` events.

Comment: @wOxxOm does the DOM listener "override" (`e.preventDefault()`) the pre-assigned responses?

Comment: Only if you do it explicitly.

Comment: Can you post an example as an answer on how to override and restore default behaviour? I'm not to familiar with js

Comment: You can find examples/tutorials if you search for the terms I've used in my first comment.